The unit digit of $\prod_{k=0}^{97}\left(2+\alpha_{k}^2\right)$, where $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,....,\alpha_{97}$ are the $98^{th}$ roots of unity


The unit digit of $$\prod_{k=0}^{97}\left(2+\alpha_{k}^2\right)$$, where $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,....,\alpha_{97}$ are the $98^{th}$ roots of unity


My Approach: Since $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,....,\alpha_{97}$ are $98^{th}$ roots of unity so $z^{98}-1=0$
Hence $z^{98}-1=(z-\alpha_0)(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2).....(z-\alpha_{97})$
Replacing $z=2$ didnot help me.
Then I wrote $2+\alpha_{k}^2=(\sqrt2+i\alpha_k)(\sqrt2-i\alpha_k)=(-\alpha_k+i\sqrt2)(\alpha_k+i\sqrt2)$
Hence  $\prod_{k=0}^{97}(2+\alpha_k^2)=\prod_{k=0}^{97}(i\sqrt2-\alpha_k)\prod_{k=0}^{n}(i\sqrt2+\alpha_k)$
$(i\sqrt2)^{98}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{97}(i\sqrt2-\alpha_k)$
and $(-i\sqrt2)^{98}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{97}(-1)^{98}(i\sqrt2+\alpha_k)$
$\implies \prod_{k=0}^{97}=\left((i\sqrt2)^{98}-1\right)\left((-i\sqrt2)^{98}-1\right)=(2^{49}+1)^2$
Hence unit digit is $9$ but answer given is $5$
Where am I making mistake?

Where is the answer given as 5?

@BrianMoehring In my assignment

Okay... "your assignment is wrong".

Indeed, despite a tiny (local and harmless) mistake: $$(\sqrt2+i\alpha_k)(\sqrt2-i\alpha_k)=\color{red}-(-\alpha_k+i\sqrt2)(\alpha_k+i\sqrt2).$$

Your answer is correct.  Here's another way to see the same result:
Instead, note that $x\mapsto x^2$ takes the set of 98th roots of unity onto the set of 49th roots of unity and the map is two-to-one.
Therefore, your product is equal to
$$\left(\prod_{k=0}^{48}(2+\beta_k)\right)^2$$
where $\beta_0, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{48}$ are the 49th roots of unity.
In particular,
$$\left(\prod_{k=0}^{48}(2+\beta_k)\right)^2 = \left(\prod_{k=0}^{48}(-2-\beta_k)\right)^2 = \left((-2)^{49}-1\right)^2 = (2^{49}+1)^2.$$

Another way:
Let $2+a_k^2=b_k$ where $0\le k\le97$
If $a_k,0\le k\le97$ is a root of $x^{98}-1=0,$
$b_k$ will be roots of   $\displaystyle(y-2)^{49}=1\iff y^{49}-\binom{49}1y^{48}2^1+\cdots+\binom{49}{48}y(-2)^{48}+(-2)^{49}-1=0$
By Vieta's formula,
$$\prod_{k=0}^{48}b_k=-\dfrac{-(2^{49}+1)}1$$
As $a_k,0\le k\le97$ is a root of $x^{98}-1=0$ so will be $-a_k$ as $(-x)^{98}-1=0$
$$\prod_{k=0}^{97}(2+a_k^2)=\prod_{k=0}^{48}(2+a_k^2)(2+(-a_k)^2)=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{48}b_k\right)^2=?$$
